# Got Binary Data when not Reconstructing a Packet in Android

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io, binary-data, socket.io-java-client

I exchanged binary data through a socket. I used socket library in

> https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java

There is an error when I receive the socket using `socket.on`. The error is :

> got binary data when not reconstructing a packet

Please help me. Below is my server code:

```
`socket.on('binary Data', function(byteArray)` 
`{socket.emit('message',byteArray);});`
```